# Child fragment triggers onClick of parent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using nested fragments, passing from one to the other with code

```
ImageView search = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.parent, ChildFragment.newInstance());
            transaction.commit();               
        }           
    });
```

However sometimes it happens that from the child fragment I can still click items of the parent fragment, even if they are invisible (covered by the child fragment). In particular, this happens when the child has a simple layout of type

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:background="#FFF0D1"
    android:id="@+id/child">

...some stuff...    

</RelativeLayout>
```

but it does NOT happen when I use the nested layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:background="#FFF0D1"
    android:id="@+id/child">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

...same stuff...

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody knows why this happens?

Comment: yupp. it happened with me. the only solution was to remove the parent fragment durinf transaction (u can add it to back stack_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason**: if you don't intercept/handle click in the child fragment - it will be passed to the parent fragment. Even if you handle clicks on **some** elements it doesn't change the whole situation.

**Easiest solution**: to avoid this behavior - declare **most outer layout** of your **child** fragment clickable like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    ...>    
    ...
```

You don't even have to implement `onClickListener` in this case

Comment: You may handle clicks on particular elements. If you click these elements - click won't be passed to the parent fragment. But if you click in any other place - it will. So please try my recommendation. If it doesn't work I will think again